# Web Audio Related React Problems

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-audio-api

This is my first stack overflow so I'm sorry in advance.

This is a web audio API question, relating to React Hooks (specifically useContext/useReducer - the dream team).

BASICALLY... I've been trying to use web audio API to create an oscillator and a slider to control it. So far, so good, and in vanilla JS I managed it by using setInterval() and listening for the changes:

```
    setInterval(() => {
    if (!osc) {
      console.log("Oscillator is stopped");
    } else {
      let freqSliderVal = document.getElementById("freq-slide").value;
      osc.frequency.value = freqSliderVal;
      osc.type = selectedWaveform;
      console.log(`Oscillator is playing. Frequency value is ${freqSliderVal}`);
    }
  }, 50);
```

I can change the frequency of the note and the waveform without the note stopping and everything's grand. You can probably see where this one's going. React basically hates this because every time you move the slider, as you can predict, it rerenders the page because the audio context is inside a useEffect. I'm aware that in the dependencies I have it re rendering every time the frequency changes, but that was the only way I could get it to actually register the change in frequency:

```
useEffect(() => {
let audioContext = new AudioContext();
let osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
osc.type = waveform;
osc.frequency.value = freq;

osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
osc.start(audioContext.currentTime);
osc.stop(audioContext.currentTime + 3);

audioContextRef.current = audioContext;
audioContext.suspend();

return () => osc.disconnect(audioContext.destination);
}, [freq, waveform]);
```

How could I make it so that:

a) I can move the fader in real time to control the frequency of the output?
2. I can change the waveform (controlled with a Context and linked to another component), also in real time?

Any help you can provide would be absolutely wonderful, as I'm beginning to really hate React now after everything started so wonderfully.

Thanks!

Sam

Comment: How do you trigger this frequency change? Do you have a dom element that you drag to a new position? Let me know to see how best to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Stavros, thanks for your response! I have this...
       <input
            name="freqSlide"
            type="range"
            className="slider"
            id="freq-slide"
            min="20"
            max="1000"
            onChange={(e) => onSlide(e)}
          />
Which is the element, and this...

  const onSlide = (e) => {
    const note = e.target.value;
    setFreq(note);
  };

Which is the function attached to it.

Comment: I think I was able to cover what you needed with my answer, I tested it and it works as expected. Let me know if something doesn't align with your app's logic.

Answer (score 0):

I created a separate component with the input slider that does what you want. I defined an audioContext outside of the component to avoid re-defining it in every state update.
Since I don't know how you handle the start and stop I just start it on component load but you can easily update that with a `useEffect` in your component. The way it is now you will here the sound when you move the slider.

The component is the following:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from 'react';

const audioContext = new AudioContext();
const osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
osc.type = 'square';
osc.start();
const Osc = (props) => {
  const [freq, setFrequency] = useState(0);
  const { waveform } = props;
  const onSlide = (e) => {
    const { target } = e;
    setFrequency(target.value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    osc.frequency.value = freq;
    osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
    return () => osc.disconnect(audioContext.destination);
  }, [freq]);

  useEffect(() => {
    osc.type = waveform;
  }, [waveform]);

  return (
    <input
      name="freqSlide"
      type="range"
      min="20"
      max="1000"
      onChange={(e) => onSlide(e)}
    />
  );
};

export default Osc;
```

To use it you first need to import it:

`import Osc from './osc';`

And use it in your render function:

`<Osc waveform="square" />`

The waveform is a property since you said you update it from a different component so you can update it here and the update will be reflected in the component.